# clearInterval automatically

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm having a problem with how can I stop automatically the auto_refresh of my script.
Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh_question(){        
        var url = "/question.do";       
        jQuery('#question').load(url, function myFunction(reponse, status, xhr){
             if(reponse=="fin")
            {
              clearInterval(auto_refresh );
            }           

        }).fadeIn("slow");  
    }   
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(refresh_question, 4000);     
</script>
```

The idea behind this script is that I want to display a new question of my DB each 4 seconds, but after the 10th question I should stop the quiz, means turn off the auto_refresh. How can I do so?

Comment: You can just add a counter variable right outside the function, increment the counter inside the function, and call `clearInterval` in the function if the counter is 10.

Comment: Your current code should work by clearing the interval if the server sent "fin" as response. What error you get?

Comment: No it doenst, 'cuz the auto_refresh still refreshing and that throws exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a counter that is incremented each time the refresh been called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numberOfRefreshes = 0;
    var auto_refresh = 0;

    function refresh_question(){        
        var url = "/question.do";       
        jQuery('#question').load(url, function myFunction(reponse, status, xhr){
            numberOfRefreshes++; 

            if(numberOfRefreshes == 10)
            {
              clearInterval(auto_refresh);
            }           

        }).fadeIn("slow");  
    }   
    auto_refresh = setInterval(refresh_question, 4000);     
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx, I tried yesterday something like that but it didnt work
I'll try one more time :)

Comment: The problem is that the var "auto_refresh" is not known inside "myFunction" I'm not sure but I think so!!

Comment: @ABDOZeidane I have moved the variable definition.

Comment: Oops my bad it works, thank u very much, I appreciate ur help :)

Comment: I was testing numberOfRefreshes == 10 whereas I've only 3 questions in my DB, Thnx again